# Java regular expression - multiline

Tags: java, regex

I have a large array with string. I need to use the string in the array to form patterns. However for the string in the text could be across several lines. the constructed patterns don't work with the multiline flag. Could anyone point out what is wrong? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
String[] phrases = new String[2];
    phrases[0] = "student (male)";
    phrases[1] = "worker (female)";

    Pattern[] ptn = new Pattern[phrases.length];

    int i = 0;
    for (String p : phrases)
    {
        p = Pattern.quote(p);
        System.out.println(p);
        ptn[i] = Pattern.compile(p+"\\:\\s\\w+",Pattern.MULTILINE);
        i++;
    }

    String text = "student\n(male): John";
    System.out.println(text);

    for(Pattern p : ptn)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have several problems, not the least of which is that your patterns can never match given the sample inputs/outputs; can you have these strings rewritten?

Comment: The input string array is read from a file. The text is also read from a file. So all modification of the strings have to be done in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you don't need that MULTILINE flag:

As @fge explained earlier, that flag only means that `^` (and `$`) will match the **begin** (and **end**) of **each** line in the tested String.
Reminder: the default behavior (without that flag) would cause `^` and `$` to match respectively the begin and the end **of the whole String**.

---

If you want to match, at some point, either a **space** or a **new line**, I would suggest you to try matching `\s`.

However, if you replace the following lines:

```
phrases[0] = "student (male)";
phrases[1] = "worker (female)";
```

by:

```
phrases[0] = "student\\s(male)";
phrases[1] = "worker\\s(female)";
```

Then you won't be able to use `Pattern#quote` to *escape* the parenthesis. I believe that the simplest way is to directly escape them yourself as follow:

```
phrases[0] = "student\\s\\(male\\)";
phrases[1] = "worker\\s\\(female\\)";
```

---

If you actually can't modify these Strings, you may just change:

```
p = Pattern.quote(p);
```

for:

```
p = p.replaceAll("(\\(|\\))", "\\\\"+"$1").replaceAll(" ", "\\\\s");
```

This will:

- escape the `(` and `)`
- replace the spaces () by `\s` to match either spaces or new lines.

Here is an [Ideone link](https://ideone.com/4TYXhe) to some executable example of how your code could be :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 for also noticing the need to `Pattern.quote()`! By the way, you could do with editing your post and re-adding back the explanation about `Pattern.MULTILINE` vs `Pattern.DOTALL` ;)

Comment: The problem is that I can't manually modify each array as there are too many data. The created pattern doesn't work using replacing:p = p.replaceAll("\\(", "\\(");
and p = p.replaceAll("\\)", "\\)"); So it seems that I have to use Pattern#quote, which I just learnt from you in a different post.

Comment: Hmmm... ok! Then, just leave most of your code unchanged and simply replace `Pattern.quote(p)` by `p.replaceAll("(\\(|\\))", "\\\\"+"$1").replaceAll(" ", "\\\\s")`

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/4TYXhe) is a link to an online executable example of how your code could be :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a hero :-)

Comment: Ahahah, thank you :) Don't forget to accept the answer if you're done with that question ;) And good luck with your project!